# Problem with loading resource Files in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, resources

so I am currently working on two JavaFX Projects and on both I have following lines of Code:

```
package com.fire.example;

import com.fire.example.database.SQLiteDatabase;
import com.fire.example.services.BackupService;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Objects;

public class FireApp extends Application {

    private final BackupService backupService = new BackupService();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = new SQLiteDatabase();
        if (sqLiteDatabase.openDBConnection()) {
            sqLiteDatabase.initDB();
        }
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        backupService.createBackUpFolder();
        backupService.createAutomaticBackup();
        backupService.deleteBackupsOlderThanOneWeek();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            try {
                Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(FireApp.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com.fire.example/pages/LoginPage.fxml")));
                Scene loginScene = new Scene(root,1000,700);
                stage.setScene(loginScene);
                stage.setResizable(false);
                stage.setOnCloseRequest(e -> {
                    Platform.exit();
                    System.exit(0);
                });
                stage.setTitle("Fire App");
                stage.centerOnScreen();
                stage.show();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How ever, when I am trying to start the Project over IntelliJ IDE it works perfectly fine.
But when starting either of the projects via ./gradlew run, it throws a Nullpointer at

```
FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(FireApp.class.getClassLoader().getResource("com.fire.example/pages/LoginPage.fxml")));
```

[image: Also this is my File Structure:]

I get that it must have something to do with how the IDE and how gradlew loads the resources.

I have tried creating a jpackage and looking for the file structure but everything seems fine.
Right now I have no ideads on how to fix this problem.

Any Help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(Objects.requireNonNull(FireApp.class.getResource("/com.fire.example/pages/LoginPage.fxml")));`

Comment: This actually worked. How did I not think of this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't really do any JavaFX but it seems odd to have packages under `resources`

Comment: @g00se Why is it odd to have packages under `resources`? How else would you organise your resources? The usual resource path here would be `/com/fire/example/pages/LoginPage.fxml`, assuming the IDE is showing a *package* `com.fire.example` and not a file system folder actually called `com.fire.example`.

Comment: Because packages are a means of producing protection domains for *code*. In, say, a Swing program, from the resources root, it's normal to have different folders, such as `images` `sounds` etc. Maybe resource folders are much more complex in JavaFX?

Comment: @g00se Resources are just deployed to the classpath (or the module path if you are creating a module). The only difference between the resources structure and the src structure is that, using the standard layout, the build tool will compile .java files in the src hierarchy before placing the resulting class file in the classpath, but for resources it will simply copy the files over. `Class.getResource(...)` at an intuitive level simply means "load this resource from the place this class came from", so it makes sense from that perspective to organize resources in the same structure as classes.

Comment: In a large project, organizing resources by type (images, sounds, fxml, whatever) soon becomes unmanageable. It's much better to organize them by the logical unit of the program. So `com.example.app.ui.main` might contain the classes and resources for the main view, `com.example.app.ui.editor` the classes and resources for an editor subview, etc. That is much more scalable as the program complexity increases, and you rarely need to resort to the classpath root to load a resource. (The path in the OP here can be `FireApp.class.getResource("pages/Login.fxml")`, for example.)

Comment: @James_D I think I'd need to see a listing of a deployment unit to be 100% certain of what you're saying. You seem to be saying that the build process is going to place the resources in with the binaries, which personally I'd hate if that were the case

Comment: @g00se Yes, of course. Why do you object to that? The resources are just as much a part of the application as the class files. Everything has to end up in the jar file if the application is bundled as a jar. If you use IntelliJ you can just create a standard JavaFX application and look in the target/classes folder. Note, in reference to a previous comment, that the module system also provides some protection domains for resources, as well as for code.

Comment: @g00se I do a deep dive into exactly this in my article: https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/resources .  As to the solution to this problem, it's probably better to drop the "com.fire.example/" rather then put a "/" at the beginning, also drop the getClassLoader().  The Class is going to supply the package coordinates - which is what you probably want if you're putting the resources where they are in this example.

Comment: Yes, if the resources are really going to go in with the classes then the package-relative shorter path is probably better

Comment: @g00se "_which personally I'd hate if that were the case_" – Not sure I understand. Resources are packaged with the class files. They always have been. That's not even a JavaFX thing, it's standard Java. Note even in your Swing example, the `images`, `sounds` and so on folders are still considered "packages".

Comment: @Slaw I mean mixed into the same 'directories'. e.g `/foo/bar/x.class` along with `/foo/bar/x.png`.

Comment: @g00se Ah, that makes more sense. Though how often do you look at the class files after packaging your application, where seeing non-class files next to them could be bothersome? Also, note that resources can be encapsulated if the library/application is modular; you can control if other modules have access to the resources by `opens` their packages or not (though that can be an argument against placing them in the same package as classes).

Comment: Not often I suppose other on sites such as this when I ask for a listing for people with problems ;)

Comment: My point is that "hate" is a strong reaction to have for something you likely never directly look at to begin with. Assuming you weren't being hyperbolic.